# Finding Riemannian metric explicitly from the conformal structure on a surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Each Riemann surface structure $S'$ on a topological surface $S$ can be obtained from a Riemannian metric which looks like $ds^{2} = g_{11}dx^{2} + 2g_{12}dxdy + g_{22}dy^{2}$ in local coordinates where $g = \begin{pmatrix}g_{11}&g_{12}\\g_{12}&g_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ is a smooth metric. My question is can we find the metric explicitly from a given conformal structure on the topological surface $S$ in certain cases? For example, in the case of a classical Schottky groups for which $2g$ disjoint circles in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ are paired by Mobius transformations $a_{i}$, $1\leq i\leq g$, this gives an explicit conformal structure on the genus $g$ handlebody, is there a way to find the metric explicitly? My goal is to find the Beltrami differential associated with such a structure.

Comment: What does "finding the metric explicitly from a given conformal structure" mean? How is the conformal structure given if it is not given by a metric (which generates a conformal class)?

Comment: For a classical Schottky groups, if I am not mistaken about the terminology, specifying the particular pairing Mobius maps between the circles is what I meant by a conformal structure on the genus g surface. So my question is whether there is a way to find the metric explicitly from that data.